# Python destroy only tkinter subclass widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, subclass

I wrote a subclass with tkinter widgets. In a for-loop i place few of them in a Frame. This Frame also contains a Label and a Entry. 
Now i want to destroy all of my subclass widgets but NOT the Label and the Entry.

I tried it like this:

```
for child in self.frame.winfo_children():
    if child.winfo_class() == "???":
         [...]
```

But I wasnt able to figure out what i have to use, so i will use ??? as a placeholder for this.

I place them in a rule with this Code:

```
db.execute("SELECT * FROM UsedSystems")
rows = db.fetchall()
i = 0

for row in rows:
    image_path = activepath+rows[i][0]
    name = rows[i][1]
    performance = rows[i][2]
    project = rows[i][3]
    date = rows[i][4]              

    self.e10 = CustomWidget(self.frame, image_path, name, performance, project, date)
    self.e10.grid(row=1+i,column=0, columnspan=2)

    i+=1
```

Comment: Why not just keep a reference to these widgets in a list, and then iterate over the list to delete the widgets?

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `isinstance` built-in function to check the class (as shown below):

```
for child in self.frame.winfo_children():
    if not (isinstance (child, Label) or isinstance (child, Entry)):
        child.destroy ()
```

This will destroy any widget if they are not a `Label` and `Entry`. However, it cannot distinguish between different `Label` widgets (for example) and will leave BOTH.